# Detecting mobile device from static HTML page on Windows server

Tags: windows, iis, mobile

I need to implement mobile device detection on a static HTML website.  JavaScript isn't an option since many devices have it disabled or don't support it.  The site is on a Windows server and as I normally work with a LAMP stack I'm not sure what my options are. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's depends on what do you expect to do after the detection. If you you only want to change the style of your HTML page, you can just add different CSS files in your HTML header section.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="screen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" href="mobile.css" />
```

The first line will applied screen.css to your web page when user browse with standard monitor. The second line will be applied when browsing with a mobile device.

Other than simple style changes, I don't think you can do too much on static HTML.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it needs to redirect to a completely seperate mobile site with a different structure and content.